# Web Api Autofac InstancePerRequest

Tags: c#, attributes, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I have a custom AuthorizationFilter Attribute on my Web Api project like this

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class GenericAuthenticationFilter :  AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Public default Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public GenericAuthenticationFilter()
    {
    }

    private readonly bool _isActive = true;

    /// <summary>
    /// parameter isActive explicitly enables/disables this filter.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="isActive"></param>
    public GenericAuthenticationFilter(bool isActive)
    {
        _isActive = isActive;
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Checks basic authentication request
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext filterContext)
    {

        if (!_isActive) return;
        var identity = FetchAuthHeader(filterContext);
        if (identity == null)
        {
            ChallengeAuthRequest(filterContext);
            return;
        }
        var genericPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = genericPrincipal;
        if (!OnAuthorizeUser(identity.Name, identity.Password, filterContext))
        {
            ChallengeAuthRequest(filterContext);
            return;
        }

        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
```

My StartUpClass is like this

```
  public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        // Get your HttpConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
        // rather than using GlobalConfiguration.
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        IoC.Instance.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        config.DependencyResolver =
        new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
        // Register your Web Api controllers.
        IoC.Instance.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();
        IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);
        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
        // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }
}
```

and my IoC class where all dependencies are resolved is like this

```
public class IoC : ContainerBuilder
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private readonly static IoC _instance = new IoC();

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private static object _lock;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private IContainer _componentsContainer;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static IoC Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IContainer GetComponentsContainer()
    {
        if (_componentsContainer == null)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_componentsContainer == null)
                    _componentsContainer = this.Build();
            }
        }

        return _componentsContainer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T Resolve<T>() where T : class
    {
        return GetComponentsContainer().Resolve<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ILifetimeScope BeginLifetimeScope()
    {
        return GetComponentsContainer().BeginLifetimeScope();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private IoC()
    {
        _lock = new object();
        ConfigureDependencies();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private void ConfigureDependencies()
    {
        //Configure all your depedendencies here!!

        //Database connection
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;
        this.Register(c => new SqlConnection(connectionString)).As<IDbConnection>().InstancePerRequest();// InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        //Database Connection OrmLite
        OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqlServerDialect.Provider;
        //Register Repositories
        this.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>().InstancePerRequest();// InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        // Register Services
        this.RegisterType<UserService>().As<IUserService>().InstancePerRequest();// InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        this.RegisterType<TokenService>().As<ITokenService>().InstancePerRequest();
        this.RegisterType<DKMenuService>().As<IDKMenuService>().InstancePerRequest();// InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        this.RegisterType<DKGRIDTblService>().As<IDKGRIDTblService>().InstancePerRequest();// InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        this.RegisterType<FKService>().As<IFKService>().InstancePerRequest();// InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        this.RegisterType<LOVService>().As<ILOVService>().InstancePerRequest();// InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        this.RegisterType<JobService>().As<IJobService>().InstancePerRequest();// InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        this.RegisterType<MADEService>().As<IMADEService>().InstancePerRequest();// InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    }

}
```

And I decorate my Controllers with this filter like this

```
[GenericAuthenticationFilter]
    public AuthenticateController(ITokenService tokenService)
    {
        _tokenService = tokenService;
    }
```

My Problem is that the OnAuthorazation method of the GenericAuthenticationFilter is never fired.
If on the IoC Class class I change InstancePerRequest to InstancePerLifetimeScope everything works ok, but I want my dependencies to work per Request

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is part or all of your issue, but... you can only build a `ContainerBuilder` once. In `Startup.Configuration()` I see on lines 11-12:

```
config.DependencyResolver =
new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
```

And `IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer()` calls `Build()` to create the container.

But just two lines later I see you're adding more components to the container, and after that I see a second call:

```
app.UseAutofacMiddleware(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
```

Based on your code, that's going to be the same container that was built *before you added the new registrations*. The container won't include the API controllers, the model binders, or the filter provider.

I'm actually not sure why you're not having *more* problems than you're having now.

Try moving the *setting* of the containers (the calls to `IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer()`) until *all the way at the end*, after you've finished registering all of your dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

The only configuration that worked was the following

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        // Get your HttpConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
        // rather than using GlobalConfiguration.
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
        // Register your Web Api controllers.
        IoC.Instance.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();

        config.DependencyResolver =
        new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
        // Register your Web Api controllers.
        //IoC.Instance.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        //IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        //IoC.Instance.RegisterWebApiModelBinderProvider();

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
        // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

    }
}
```

I am still not sure whether it is right.
Examples of usage. I have a filter like the following

```
public class ApiAuthenticationFilter : GenericAuthenticationFilter
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Default Authentication Constructor
    /// </summary>
    public ApiAuthenticationFilter()
    {

    }
```

}

A method in this filter is using a service which is resolved like this

```
protected override bool OnAuthorizeUser(string username, string password, HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var provider = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService(typeof(IUserService)) as IUserService;
```

}

My controllers on the other hand do not have parameterless constructors and the dependencies are resolved automatically

```
public class DKMenuController : ApiController
{
    #region Private variable.

    private readonly ITokenService _tokenService;
    private readonly IDKMenuService _dkMenuService;
    private readonly IUserService _userservice;
    private const string Token = "Token";

    #endregion

    #region Public Constructor

    /// <summary>
    /// Public constructor to initialize DKMenu service instance
    /// </summary>
    public DKMenuController(ITokenService tokenService, IUserService userservice, IDKMenuService dkMenuService)
    {
        _tokenService = tokenService;
        _dkMenuService = dkMenuService;
        _userservice = userservice;
    }
```

}

I don't know whether it is correct but it works